# EditText Java Code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

I'm building a quiz app in Android Studio. One of my questions has an EditText to write in the answer. I am stuck on how to determine the score for this answer. Is it a boolean or a string? Here is what I have:

```
    EditText q4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer4_Wakanda);
    Boolean q4RightAnswer = q4.isChecked();
```

I know this is wrong. I had a string and changed it to a boolean, which is where I got stuck. It's possible that the whole thing is wrong. I just want my app to recognize the right answer, in order to give it 1 point.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am a new coder so I could really use a hand!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `isChecked()` on an EditText. To recognise the right answer you would simply have to compare the user's input in the EditText with the correct answer. I.e.

```
String userAns = q4.getText().toString();
if (userAns.equals(correctAns)) {
    // correct, add 1 point
}
else {
    // incorrect, do something else
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, if not I would need some further clarification on what the issue is, or perhaps a larger portion of your code.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about. I just have to figure out how to incorporate it into my code. My xml is good, I've just been having trouble with my java. I will post my java above if you don't mind looking at it.

Comment: Go ahead. I'll have a look.